# In C#, what does an nvarchar with length of -1 mean?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I created a new ASP.net MVC project with individual user accounts. I'm looking through the database schema that's created and noticed that several fields have a length attribute of -1. Some are nvarchar and others are varbinary. What does the -1 indicate?

[image]

Comment: nvarchar is a sql server type, not a C# type.

Comment: It means `nvarchar(max)`.  See the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nvarchar` is a SQL Server type. A length of -1 here means that it is an `nvarchar(MAX)`